# Read file of any name by date with PL / SQL using UTL_FILE

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, utl-file

I am working on a procedure to read files from PL / SQL I have managed to read a specific file but now I want to do it dynamic because I will have multiple files starting with the date for example:

- 20190218 111833_Worker.dat
- 20190218 114249_Job.dat
- 20190218 114353_Organizations

What I need is to read the most recent file of that example presented.

Any opinion is appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Is there a strict need to do this in PL/SQL?  `utl_file` does not have a way to get the list of files in a directory.  You can create a Java stored procedure to do that and then consume the result of the Java stored procedure in PL/SQL.  If you need to stay purely in PL/SQL, depending on the Oracle version you may be able to use `dbms_scheduler` to call out to the operating system but that tends to get a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

"How do I list files in a directory using PL/SQL" has been asked before (e.g. [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404708/listing-files-in-a-specified-directory-using-pl-sql), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271954/how-to-read-all-files-of-an-oracle-directory-with-pl-sql-and-update-a-blob-colum)). You have several options:

- Use external tables with a preprocessor script - [example 1](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513), [example 2](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2015/04/25/getting-a-file-listing-from-a-directory-in-plsql/)
- Create a java class - [example 1](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2010/08/directory-file-list-in-plsql/), [example 2](https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/query-up-a-list-of-files-from-os-directory/)
- Use `SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE.searchFiles` with the undocumented `X$KRBMSFT` - [example 1](http://abilim.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-list-files-on-directory-from.html), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596927/using-pl-sql-how-do-i-open-a-directory) (I couldn't get this to work on 12c, it's possible that it only works on 11g and earlier)

Once you have a way to select a list of your filenames, you can just do an order by and filter it to return only the first row, e.g.

```
select filename
from my_file_list
order by substr(filename, 1, 15) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```